# Erro: table name specified more than once

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Criei uma coluna inclusao na tabela app, ela funciona pra registrar a data de compra do aplicativo e terei que atualizar os registros antigos com a data de criação de usuário.
Fiz uma query para resolver o problema, mas o postgreSQL acusa um erro:

> ERROR:  table name "app" specified more than once

Essa é minha query:

```
UPDATE app
  SET app.inclusao = usuario.inclusao
  FROM app, usuario
  WHERE app.usuario = usuario.codigo
```

Como faço pra resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update app
    set inclusao = usuario.inclusao
    from usuario
    where app.usuario = usuario.codigo
```

Comment: `ERROR:  column "app" of relation "app" does not exist` não funcionou.

Comment: Agora foi, digitei app errado. ;D

Comment: @Haxz se a resposta resolveu seu problema, marque ela como correta.